# Python append adding extra paratheses [] to json file when mergng two json files

Tags: python, json

Hi I am currently trying to merge multiple json files with the same structure to one json file.

Appending works but it is adding the parentheses [] to the new file with the resulting json file.

The code is getting the main json filename.txt and adding filename**_1**.txt to find it, it will open it, open filename**_2**.txt get a list and adding it to filename**_1**.txt

Result Json file:

```
{
    "DateTimeUTC": "/Date(1590149927318)/",
    "Journals": [
        {
            "JournalNumber": 1,
            "JournalLines": [
                {
                    "JournalLineID": "a",
                    "AccountID": "1a"
                }
            ]
        },
        [
            {
                "JournalDate": "/Date(1415836800000+0000)/",
                "JournalNumber": 2,
                "JournalLines": [
                    {
                        "JournalLineID": "a",
                        "AccountID": "2a"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

and this is the code I am using to merge the json file.

```
import json


def ConcatJsonFiles(report_path, reportName, file_number):
    file_number = file_number + 1
    print("\n Concatinating Reports....")
    for l in range(2, file_number):

        result_file = report_path[:-4]
        result_file = result_file + "_1.txt"

        print ("\n" + result_file + "\n")

        with open(result_file, 'r') as json_result_file:
            json_final_object = json.load(json_result_file)
            final_list = json_final_object[reportName]

        print(final_list)

        read_file = report_path[:-4]
        read_file = read_file + "_" + str(l) + ".txt"

        with open(read_file, 'r') as temp_json_file:
            temp_json_object = json.load(temp_json_file)
            list_to_read = temp_json_object[reportName]

        json_final_object[reportName].append(list_to_read)
        # final_list.append(list_to_read)

        with open(result_file, 'w') as json_result:
            json.dump(json_final_object, json_result, indent=4)


    print("\n Report " + reportName + " ready! > " + report_path + "\n")

# **********************************************

report_path = "/Users/kris/xero.txt"
reportName = "Journals"
total_files = 2

ConcatJsonFiles(report_path, reportName, total_files)
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding the parenthesis [] ?
Do you mean the 2nd entry `"Journals"` being an array instead of a dict ?

Comment: exactly, the 2nd entry is being added as an array not a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I don't what is in your Input files but I think You can use the `extend` method instead of the `append` method to solve your problem.

```
json_final_object[reportName].extend(list_to_read)
```